PowerBI: Cumulative sum by customer starting with the first entry number
I need help with a Power BI measure I can't get my head around:
I have data in an SQL database containing invoices and payments for all customers (= customer ledger).
What I want to do is calculate the cumulative sum (running total) of all invoices and payments (= open items) for each customer beginning with the earliest entry that is in that database per customer.
The goal is to visualize this measure via Power BI to display the open items per customer over time. The visualization shall change depending on the filters/slicers set.
So far I have come up with this DAX code, but unfortunately it won't calculate the running total:
Customer_Open_Items = CALCULATE([Open_Items], WINDOW(-1, REL, 0, REL, SUMMARIZE(ALLSELECTED('f_CustomerLedger'), 'f_CustomerLedger'[Customer_No]), ORDERBY('f_CustomerLedger'[Customer_No]), PARTITIONBY('f_CustomerLedger'[Customer_No])))```

Looking forward to your help.

Many thanks in advance ! :)

